# Formatting Datalabels in LiveCharts 2 - C#

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

I use LiveCharts 2 for my charts in Maui : https://lvcharts.com/docs/maui/2.0.0-beta.710/gallery

I can't find a way to format the data labels of my graphs...
I can change the size and the color, but I can't find any way to format the value itself.
There is a DataLabelsFormatter property which seems promising, but I can't find anywhere how to use it.

```
// Serie #1 : Author 1
ColumnSeries<double?> seriesAuthor1 = new()
{
    Values = new List<double?> { groups.ElementAt(0).MessagesCnt },
    Name = groups.ElementAt(0).Sender,
    Stroke = new SolidColorPaint(SKColor.Parse(App.thePrefs.Sender1Color)) { StrokeThickness = 2 },
    Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColor.Parse(App.thePrefs.Sender1Color)),
    DataLabelsSize = 20,
    DataLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColor.Parse(App.thePrefs.Sender1Color)),
    DataLabelsFormatter = ??? // <--
};
```

My data is double and I want to display thousand separators.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from their [repo](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/blob/6c23bff6a89ab865d444f897d76a06df3d26366d/docs/shared/datalabels.md#data-labels)

```
// The DataLabelsFormatter is a function 
// that takes the current point as parameter
// and returns a string.
// in this case we returned the PrimaryValue property as currency
DataLabelsFormatter = (point) => point.PrimaryValue.ToString("C2"),
```

Answer (score 2):

The github examples use it in the following ways:

Array of doubles

```
DataLabelsFormatter = (point) => point.PrimaryValue.ToString("C2")
```

Array of user defined `Fruit` class where `Name` and `SalesPerDay` are public properties

```
DataLabelsFormatter = point => $"{point.Model?.SalesPerDay} {point.Model?.Name}"
```

Edit: seems I was a bit too slow but I'll leave this up